# DIV creates newline before its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is an example code: http://jsfiddle.net/gppjvjjs/1/

As You can see, there is editable DIV with content, which is sentences. One sentence <=> one SPAN

The problem is the newline at the beggining of the DIV block. How to remove it, keeping the format of the remaining content?

DIV content is generated programmatically using text from text file, but not included in jsfiddle, but here is the function:

```
/* Reads sentences from loaded text. */
readSentences = function(text) {
  var lines = [],
    i = 0;

  $.each(text.split("\n"), function(key, value) {
    i++;
    var wrapper  = $('<div/>'),
      span  = $('<span/>').attr('num', i),
      sentencesMatch = value.match(/([\sa-zA-Z\d]){1}.+?[\.!\?]{1}([\s]+|$)/g);
// console.log(sentencesMatch);
    if (sentencesMatch !== null && sentencesMatch.length) {
      var sentences = '';

      $.each(sentencesMatch, function(k, v) {
        var trimmedValue = $.trim(v);

        if (trimmedValue != "") {
          if (k > 0) {
            i++;
            span.attr('num', i);
          }

          span.text(trimmedValue);

          sentences += wrapper.append(span).html() + ' ';
        }
      });

      lines.push(sentences);
    }
    else {
      var trimmedValue = $.trim(value);
      span.text(trimmedValue);

      if (trimmedValue != "") {
        var line = wrapper.append(span).html() + ' ';
      } else {
        // This line creates empty span
        // var line = wrapper.append(span).html();
      }

      lines.push(line);
    }
  });

  return lines.join('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Grald @BenM Removed `white-space: pre-line;` and replaced return statement with `return lines.join('<br />');`

Thanks for giving a clue! :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you do actually have a newline character at the start of the content-editable `<div>`.

Simply remove the newline for the first `<span>` element, so that it runs directly after the `>` character of the opening `<div>` tag, as follows:

```
<div id="window-oreo" class="form-control" contenteditable><span num="1" class=""
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gppjvjjs/2/)

To do this, you might want to return a trimmed version of the text from your function that generates the `<div>`'s content, for example:

```
return $.trim( lines.join('\n'); );
```

Comment: But how to do it programmatically? I have tried string.replace('\n', ''); but it's not working.

Comment: Remove this part in your css "white-space: pre-line;"

Comment: @BenM Implemeneting it in my function, didn't worked. :/

Comment: @RudolfsJanitis Then please add the generation code and sample text to the jsFiddle. It's quite difficult to diagnose with this back and forth relationship.

Comment: @RudolfsJanitis How do you actually insert the content to `#window-oreo`?

Comment: @BenM I am using Meteor and it's templating engine. :)